# Выводится название переменной, а не содержимое

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь создать текстовый квест на Python, и возникла проблема с переменной `hero_name`,
которую я присвоил результат `input`. Проблема в том, что код выдаёт именно `hero_name`, а не то, что юзер ввёл в `input`.

сам код:

```
print("Привет, герой, решивший пройти этот небольшой квест! Готов ли ты отправиться в путешествие?\n")
answer = input("Впиши свой ответ так: ready или not_ready\n")
ready = 1
not_ready = 0
if answer == "ready": 
    print("Отлично! Поехали!")
    print("И так, у каждого из героев определённо должно быть имя. У тебя оно есть?")
    hero_name = input("Впиши сюда своё имя:")
    print("Ну что же. Привет, 'hero_name' ! ")
if answer == "not_ready": 
    print("Ну и чёрт с тобой.")
```

Answer (score 0):

если вы используете python 3.6+, то используйте `f`-строки

```
print(f"Ну что же. Привет, {hero_name} ! ")
```

Comment: Спасибо! Этот вариант тоже сработал, но выдал дополнительные ' скобки, я так понял это было из-за '{hero_name}'... Но тем не менее, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Привет, герой, решивший пройти этот небольшой квест! Готов ли ты отправиться в путешествие?\n")
answer = input("Впиши свой ответ так: ready или not_ready\n")
ready = 1
not_ready = 0
if answer == "ready": 
    print("Отлично! Поехали!")
    print("И так, у каждого из героев определённо должно быть имя. У тебя оно есть?")
    hero_name = input("Впиши сюда своё имя:")
    print(f"Ну что же. Привет, {hero_name} ! ")
if answer == "not_ready": 
    print("Ну и чёрт с тобой.")
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за правку!

Comment: :) ............